# How do I zip a folder on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, compression, zip, unzip

I have seen a lot of related questions but none really helped.
I'm trying to create a zip archive from a folder (on the iPhone).

The structure of the folder is the following:

[image]

In this example the zip would be "folderToBeZipped.zip"
What is the easiest way to accomplish this and how do I unzip it (also iPhone) later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can find this project useful

http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/